# CSS - How to stretch images vertically to fill when parent div doesn't have fixed height. (Without flex)

Tags: html, css

I have 2 images that have different dimensions. I want them to align horizontally and to fill the same height.

**HTML**

```
<div class="background">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="./nat-8.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="./nat-9.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.background {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 80%;
  background-color: white;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35%;
}
```

The result I get:
[image]

As you can see the first picture has white space left on the top. How do I make it that each picture covers the whole height of parent without setting fixed height on parent?

**NOTE:** I know that it can be done with flex by setting 'display:flex' on content div. But how do I do it without flexbox?
I tried 'display:table-cell' on images, in one solution I found it was used to make divs fill the entire eight of their parent, but apparently it does not work on 'img' element.

Comment: Can you at least assume that the first image's height is necessarily smaller?

Comment: @Italy No, I would like it to work in general.

Comment: Try not using a set width on the img, but use height 100% instead

Comment: Maybe set the height of `content`?

Comment: @dantheman93 I just tried it and it gives the same result.

Comment: @Italy Yeah if I set explicit height on content it works, for example 'height: 500px' but I am interested if it can be done without specifying the height on wrapper.

Comment: Thanks, your comment about using flexbox fixed issue for me

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the height of the parent container, then you can set the height of the image to 100% to fill the space.

You can then use `object-fit:cover` to keep the image ratio rather than stretching. You can also use `object-position:center` to keep the positioning centered also.

Not all browsers are compatible with object-fit, so I would suggest swapping out the images for divs with a background-image set.

```css
.background {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper{
  height:100%;
}

.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 80%;
  background-color: white;
  height:100%;
  max-height:150px;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 35%;
  height:100%;
  object-fit:cover;
  object-position:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="content">
      <img src="https://www.indiewire.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/574055-frank_ockenfels-amc.jpg" alt="" />
      <img src="https://www.indiewire.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/574055-frank_ockenfels-amc.jpg" alt="" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```